# In Chrome @font-face local() does not find local font

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts, font-face

Google Chrome does not use font from local system and downloads from server instead, but Firefox uses it correctly from the local system.

[As I can see in DevTools, the font was downloaded from the server: DevTools -> Computed -> Rendered Fonts [img]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeL2G.png)

[In the Firefox I can see, that we use local font: FirefoxTools -> Fonts[img]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9Dxg.png)

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Calibri';
  src:  local(Calibri Italic),
        local(Calibri-Italic),
        url('../fonts/calibrii.woff2') format('woff2'), 
        url('../fonts/calibrii.woff') format('woff'), 
        url('../fonts/calibrii.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

This doesn't work if I use Calibri Italic (or Calibri Bold, 'Calibri Italic', 'Calibri-Italic', etc.). If I type `local(Calibri)`, in both browsers the font will be local.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem (just with a different font). From my experience that happens on Chrome/Windows only. The local font gets resolved properly on Chrome/Mac and other browsers.

Comment: This is an issue for me in Chromium 73 but not 80

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chrome has trouble matching local font names, as [this bugreport](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=627143) explains. In short this is caused by what the browser consideres *the* name for a font. Chrome expects the "root" name (in your case, Calibri) and deducts it needs the italic version from your `@font-face` rule. Firefox does the reverse: it looks directly for the name. [This comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=627143#c37) demonstrates that.

So it seems one approach breaks in Chrome, the other in Firefox, until this bug is fixed. I suppose it's up to you to determine which browser behaviour you want to go with.

Comment: Is it possible then just use both types of reference and get the font loaded in any case?

Comment: A possible workaround might be to declare two font families that refer to local fonts, "Calibri-Chrome" and "Calibri-Firefox" and put them in your font stack. Then add a third, "Calibri-web" for when they both fail to load. I haven't tested this, but I suppose it could work like that.