# Requests to all fonts get cancelled in Chrome 73 android using webview

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, hybrid

We have hybrid application and one of our customers updated their chrome on Android to version 73. After the update, they can't use the application and when I investigated, I see font requests that gets a status of "cancelled". Do you know any reasons why it's suddenly doing that after the update on version 73? Can you share how you handle this?
[image]

Comment: May be this is related or even the reason? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48665442/in-chrome-font-face-local-do-not-find-local-font/55452055#comment97694168_55452055