# How to set font family but retain fallback stack?

Tags: javascript, css, font-face

Is it possible to easily set a custom local font using JavaScript, but retain some default `font-family` stack in case the user tries to set a font that doesn't exist?

E.g., if the stack is `font-family: Courier, monospace;`, how to add to the beginning of the stack without resorting to manipulating strings?

Comment: A font-family property value with more than one font listed (or "font stack") already provides fallback, so I take your only question as being how to prepend to an existing stack, and how to do so specifically without manipulating strings.

Comment: @Kaiido I would've thought that'd work, but it doesn't (unless you want serif, in the case of Firefox, at least).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1: CSS custom properties

The original answer below (method 2) had some issues, but then I came up with a more straightforward solution using [CSS custom properties (variables)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties).

```css
p {
    font-family: var(--userfont), Courier, monospace;
}
```

```js
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--userfont', 'Arial');
// Result is equivalent to font-family: Arial, Courier, monospace;

document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--userfont', 'non existant');
// Result is equivalent to font-family: 'non existant', Courier, monospace;
// which falls back to Courier assuming 'non existant' isn't actually the name of
// an installed font
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0x3y9anr/)

#### Support

[Check here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables)

Unlike method 2 below, this method is supported by Edge v15+. Also it avoids the bug in older versions of Chromium that method 2 suffers from.

---

### Method 2: FontFace

You can use [@font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face), or rather the JavaScript API [FontFace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFace/FontFace).

```css
p {
  font-family: userfont, Courier, monospace;
}
```

```js
function setUserFont(fontName) {
    const userFontFace = new FontFace('userfont', `local(${fontName})`);
    document.fonts.add(userFontFace);
}

setUserFont('Arial');
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hw71jpmc/)

#### Support

[Check here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_fontface)

Old/non-Chromium Edge (up to v18) does not support the JavaScript API.

It appears [there is a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48665442/in-chrome-font-face-local-does-not-find-local-font) in Chromium 73 whereby fonts such as "Segoe UI Light" will not be found, only the base "Segoe UI" will be found. This applies to `@font-face` as well. It seems to be fixed as of Chrome 80.

Comment: you're right of course, think I know where I fudged my test